# MySQL CLI Client shows data as Hex

Tags: mysql

My MySQL CLI client when connecting to a database is automatically showing the data as hex

Connecting in CLI using `mysql -u user -p'password' -h host -P port --ssl-mode=DISABLED`

To turn this off I have to run it with the `--skip-binary-as-hex` option to see the data properly

Need help understanding what is causing this is getting enabled by default.
This issue does not exist for other users logging into the same database and is not an issue for me I connect through a DB tool, it occurs only on CLI

Comment: From the documentation of `--binary-as-hex`: **As of MySQL 8.0.19, when mysql operates in interactive mode, this option is enabled by default.**

Comment: So it sounds like you may be using a newer client than the other users. Or maybe they disable it in their `.my.cnf` files.

Comment: You can change your default in your `.my.cnf` file.

Answer (score 4):

Prior to MySQL 8.0.19, the issue which you are facing did not exist. `binary-as-hex` client option is enabled by default from MySQL 8.0.19 Command Line Client.

Run `status` or `\s` in MySQL Command Line Client. You will notice a line about binary data like this:

```
Binary data as: Hexadecimal
```

You can refer these links for more information:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_char
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_binary-as-hex